# Vue component taking few time to load in blade Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm using Vue component to Laravel blade page. The problem is while loading the page the Vue component not immediately rendered. It's taking 0.5/1/1.5 seconds later(Like eye blink).

Please check my screenshots:

1. While loading - https://prnt.sc/F5-AlfAVtwYt
2. After loading - https://prnt.sc/SGpnkV8l-atP

Comment: How you expect  us to solve it without code :D

Comment: Which code should I attach to determine the problem?

Comment: the one that loads component maybe